# Custom draw items in ComboBoxCell

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to draw items in a ComboBoxCell in a DataGridView using the DrawItem Event. Following is my code.

Updated Code:

```
private void dgv_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        int index = dgv.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
        if (index == FormatColumnIndex)
        {
            var combobox = e.Control as ComboBox;
            if (combobox == null)
                return;
            combobox.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
            combobox.DrawItem -= combobox_DrawItem;
            combobox.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(combobox_DrawItem);
        }            
    }

void combobox_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Index < 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        int index = dgv.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
        if (index == e.Index)
        {
            DataGridViewComboBoxCell cmbcell = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dgv.CurrentRow.Cells["ProductFormat"];

            string productID = dgv.Rows[cmbcell.RowIndex].Cells["ProductID"].Value.ToString();

                string item = cmbcell.Items[e.Index].ToString();
                if (item != null)
                {
                    Font font = new System.Drawing.Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 8);
                    Brush backgroundColor;
                    Brush textColor;

                    if (e.State == DrawItemState.Selected)
                    {
                        backgroundColor = SystemBrushes.Highlight;
                        textColor = SystemBrushes.HighlightText;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        backgroundColor = SystemBrushes.Window;
                        textColor = SystemBrushes.WindowText;
                    }
                    if (item == "Preferred" || item == "Other")
                    {
                        font = new Font(font, FontStyle.Bold);
                        backgroundColor = SystemBrushes.Window;
                        textColor = SystemBrushes.WindowText;
                    }                        


                    if (item != "Select" && item != "Preferred" && item != "Other")
                        e.Graphics.DrawString(item, font, textColor, new Rectangle(e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y, e.Bounds.Width, e.Bounds.Height));
                    else
                        e.Graphics.DrawString(item, font, textColor, e.Bounds);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The items are displayed properly, but the dropdown seems out of place and looks awkward.

Also when I hover over the dropdown items, they seem to be painted over again which makes them look darker and blurred. How can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you use an `if-else` to draw string some strings differently (with different text bounds), in fact the Text Bounds should be extracted/calculated carefully from `e.Bounds`.

Comment: Get rid of your for...loop.  The DrawItem is to draw "one" item.

Comment: @LarsTech I removed the for loop and now the items are displayed properly. However, when I hover over the items in the combobox, they seem to be painted over again causing them to look blurred and darker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your drawing routine looks like it is confusing the RowIndex of the grid with the e.Index of the ComboBox items collection.  Different things.

Try removing this:

```
// int index = dgv.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
// if (index == e.Index) {
```

As far as the blurriness is concerned, add the following line to fix that:

```
void combobox_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e) {
  e.DrawBackground();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it by setting the TextRenderingHint property of `e.Graphics` to `SingleBitPerPixelGridFit` before calling `DrawString`:

```
        e.DrawBackground()
        e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixelGridFit
        e.Graphics.DrawString(lstr_h, e.Font, lbrush_fore, e.Bounds)
        e.DrawFocusRectangle()
```